# How can I get this PHP for loop to run even if an error occurs?

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling, try-catch

I'm aiming to get the second if statement to run if the $decode['results'][$i]['components']['ISO_3166-1_alpha-2'] throws a undefined array key error so that the 'country_code' one can be used instead.

I'm trying with PHP try, catch but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I don't know if I'm mis-using it's purpose or simply not doing it correctly.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($decode['results']); $i++){
    try{
        if ($decode['results'][$i]['components']['ISO_3166-1_alpha-2'] === $_REQUEST['isoCode']){
            // echo json_encode($decode['results'][$i]['components']['ISO_3166-1_alpha-2']);
            //sends status data and api associative array to script.js
            $output['status']['code'] = "200";
            $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
            $output['status']['description'] = "success";
            $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
            $output['data'] = $decode['results'][$i];

            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');  
                             
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($decode['results'][$i]['components']['country_code'] === $_REQUEST['isoCode']){
            // echo json_encode($decode['results'][$i]['components']['ISO_3166-1_alpha-2']);
            //sends status data and api associative array to script.js
            $output['status']['code'] = "200";
            $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
            $output['status']['description'] = "success";
            $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
            $output['data'] = $decode['results'][$i];
    
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined array keys don't throw exceptions, so you can't catch it with `try/catch`

Comment: You need to test the array key explicitly, instead of using `try`.

Comment: Try something like `$v1 = $decode['results'][$i]['components']['ISO_3166-1_alpha-2'] ?? null;`, and then test `$v1` for null in your `if`. `??` is a safe way to test deeply nested arrays: https://3v4l.org/pBQUd